# Downloading file is slow in some devices

Tags: android

i am using below code to downloading file from URL.

```
    URL url = new URL(mCoreContent.VideoURI);
HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
c.setRequestMethod("GET");
c.setDoOutput(true);
c.connect();
lenghtOfFile = c.getContentLength();
InputStream input = c.getInputStream();
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(input);
ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream((int) lenghtOfFile);
int buffer = 4096;
byte data[] = new byte[buffer];
int current = 0;
while ((current = bis.read(data, 0, buffer)) != -1) {
output.write(data, 0, current);
}
```

i tested above code with two different device. one device taking less than a minute downloading the file and another takes more than 5-10 to downloading same with same network connecting. i tested multiple times and i am getting the same result. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which devices and which versions did you test?

Comment: which service provider? Check the internet speed for normal downloading on the device and check how much time is required for your app to download it. This way you will get to know if it's your application's problem or the service proveider's problem

Comment: i am using wifi to download the file. speed upto 4mbps